# ArcGIS Python script tool empty output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-script-tool

I have a script exported from ModelBuilder for a tool that import CAD file to geodatabase.
When I run the code in a Python window in ArcMap it works just fine, and when I do using the model as well.
But when I import the script to a toolbox, the output comes out empty. However I can see the output dataset existing in the scratch gdb
and I do need it as a toolbox script so I can publish it as a geoprocessing service.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Script arguments
Input_CAD_Datasets = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if Input_CAD_Datasets == '#' or not Input_CAD_Datasets:
    Input_CAD_Datasets = "C:\\Users\\Metal\\Desktop\\stuff\\Sohar_port.dwg" # provide a default value if unspecified

Dataset = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if Dataset == '#' or not Dataset:
    Dataset = "qqwwe" # provide a default value if unspecified

output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
if output == '#' or not output:
    output = "%scratchGDB%\\qqwwe" # provide a default value if unspecified

# Local variables:
v_scratchGDB_ = "%scratchGDB%"

# Process: CAD to Geodatabase
arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion(Input_CAD_Datasets, v_scratchGDB_, Dataset, "1000","")
```

[image: the script params]

Comment: To answer the second part of your question regarding geoprocessing services: a feature dataset is not a supported output type. You'll need to modify your workflow to use a supported output if your eventual plan is to publish as a service.

Comment: @KHibma when i publish from the model directly the geoprocessing works fine and the output type is "feature datasaet"  but the CadToGeodatabase tool doesn't make the input as a parameter unless i make it a script and set the type to " File " but when i use the script that's what happens, it doesn't work even in ArcMap as toolbox script.
so i need to figure out what's wrong in any of the cases to be able to get a progress on my main objective